# VueJS component to run a MelonJS game

Tags: javascript, melonjs

I am making an application with VueJS, that launches a game with MelonJS, and then passes the score along to the mongoDB database.

At the moment, I have a .vue component that I want to inject the game into.

## This is where the game should launch

```
</template>

<style>
#game-screen {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<script>


</script>
```

The div `screen` is where the game is to run. The original game minifies the files, and on the index.html file it is injected into that div.

[This is the game that I want to use](https://github.com/ellisonleao/clumsy-bird)

I am confused when it comes to require or importing the script files. Does Vue support using such large blocks of code in a component? If I link the files in the new project html file, once the component loads will it have access to the js and css files?

I have the idea in my mind that I can require them into the component, and the it will act just like the html file.

Comment: The following comment comes from jsmilovic on our gitter chat. Maybe it will be helpful: > I haven't used Vue, but in looking at the docs it seems like each Vue has an el (Which is the element you are binding to) as well as events like ready ( https://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram ).
In melon you supply an el to render your element into ... so this person should be able to created a Vue, which requires all the game files, with an el of "#screen", and when the ready event fires trigger the game.onload() which will render onto the supplied selector (screen in this case)

Comment: Trying this now. Make so much sense, I totally forgot about using the #el in a Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a proper answer in so you have something to accept if it works, as well as some more sourcing.

Each Vue has an [el](https://vuejs.org/api/#el) -- Which is the element you are binding to -- as well as events like [ready](http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

In melon you supply an [el](http://melonjs.github.io/melonJS/docs/me.video.html#init) (This is the optional div they call a wrapper) to render your element into, so you should be able to created a Vue, which requires all the game files, with an el of "#screen", and when the ready event fires trigger the game.onload() which will render onto the supplied selector (screen in this case)